# Automatic Network Connection Fail-Over Based On Internet Connectivity Status?

Tags: networking, internet

NEW APPROACH TO MY REQUEST:
Here's what I need. Is this possible?

1. Computer is using a Wi-Fi connection (this is the connection this is all about) as the WAN connection for an internal network, and sharing that internet connection via its Ethernet connection (this Eth connection is NOT involved with, and has nothing at all to do with this request) to a real router which shares it on from there.
2. Computer has 2 Wi-Fi connections that are configured. One is set as higher priority than the other.
3. If the computer loses INTERNET connectivity on the currently connected Wi-Fi, I want it to automatically switch over to use the other, secondary  Wi-Fi connection.

---

ORIGINAL POST:
This seems simple enough to me, but I'm starting to think that's not the case, because I don't seem to be able to find anything about it, other than some questionable rabbit holes here and there. lol

I would like to be able to have my Ubuntu (20.04 LTS Desktop) automatically change from using it's Wi-Fi connection over to using one of its other (user specified) network connections (even just simply another Wi-Fi connection) IF the internet ever goes down on the Wi-Fi connection.

Is there an app for this?
If not, does anyone here have a script or anything that could assist me with this sort of thing?
I'm totally into rabbit holes if I have some assurance they'll eventually get me there. :-)

EDIT 1:

- I know how to set the priority order for network connections.
- I set one of the two Wi-Fi connections to priority 1.
- I set the other one to priority 2.
- I set all others to numbers higher than those.
  Then, in testing...
  *When I tell the network settings dialog in Settings to 'forget' the first Wi-Fi connection, the system DOES automatically switch over to the second one.
- However, that only works when I manually cause it to lose the first one.
- If the first one stays sort of semi-connected, but has some kind of problem (e.g. being required to 'sign into the network', as is periodically the case here), since it's still semi-connected, the system apparently doesn't see it as having lost it's connection (because it only cares about whether the Wi-Fi is connected, and is NOT paying any attention to whether it still has a connection to the internet), and the computer just sits here, offline (i.e. connected to Wi-Fi, but not authenticated, and thus, not connected to the internet) until I get back, and am able to authenticate it manually.

I want something that will actually pay attention to the internet connection, and if it is lost, switch to the other Wi-Fi connection.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I had an intermittent network issue that had me write a script that just ping'd a host (other side of where network was failing) and recorded some stats (esp. date & time if failure, plus counters incremented/decremented on fail/success).  If counter exceeded a threshold it spawned another script (that fixed a issue), if counter exceeded second threshold it spawned another script (I forget what it did). script then slept (zombie state) awhile before looping.  Your script shouldn't even need a `ping` (peruse `ip link` I'd expect).. but that's s dirty-hack solution until a better comes along

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea, though, whether what you just said has anything to do with what I'm asking for. That's my fault, of course. I'm sorry I'm just no up-to-speed enough to know how what you said relates.